# Diagonal SVG Stroke

Tags: css, svg, stroke

At the moment I am developing this simple site:

https://carl-robertshaw1.superhi.com/

The diagonal line is an SVG image but I what to code this SVG so that it is responsive, so it reminds at 1px on any screen, goes to the bottom left-hand corner and meets the logo in the same place, just off the 'C' of carl.

I've had a good look on here and can't find anything that would help me, can anyone help.

At the moment I have the SVG image set up like this:

```css
.image1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 77px 230px 0 0;
}


.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img class="image1" src='carl_line_mid.svg'>
</div>
```

Comment: please insert the code in the question itself: if the external url becomes invalid the question is no longer useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just insert the SVG element into the HTML DOM?

Try:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg class="image1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <line x1="100%" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" style="fill:none; stroke:#fff; stroke-width:1px;"></line>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I made some adjustments to the image. You can change the size of the svg via the style attribute (currently 100% of container), or remove the style attribute and set it with CSS. The width of the line will stay `1px`.

[See the browser support. It's great!](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5)

Comment: Amazing, thats fixed it for me. Thanks very much

Comment: If I wanted the stroke to be at 45 degrees from the top right point, would I take out the x y values and replace them with -45? What would be the CSS code here?

Comment: That doesn't work with the svg itself, because the css's width and height are stretching/shrinking the svg container. For a 45° degree you need to make the height and width the same.